# Format text on lookup popup and text inside a table

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, formatting, background

I have a multiple lookup data inside a table.
I have to format a text "Stato" with green background if it is "PRONTO CONSEGNA".

[image]

And do the same thing inside the table isolating the single "Id_uni" and not the whole cell.

Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Format a text "Stato" with green background if it is "PRONTO CONSEGNA":**

Edit the DispForm.aspx and add a Script Editor web part, enter the following scripts into the web part, then save the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ready");
function ready(){
                var oFieldValue = $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Stato")').closest('td').next('td');                          
                // use trim() function to remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string
               var fieldValue = oFieldValue.text().trim();
                if(fieldValue == 'PRONTO CONSEGNA'){
                                 oFieldValue.css("background-color", "green"); 
                }
}
</script>
```

Testing result:

[image]

**Format single "Id_Uni" in lookup column based on "Stato" in modern list:**

The lookup field object has two properties: lookupId and lookupValue. You are getting "Id_uni" as the lookup value. It cannot get the "Stato" from the lookup in JSON column formatting. In modern view, we cannot format the single "Id_Uni" in a lookup column which has multiple values. And there is now method to use scripts to a modern list.

As a workaround, you can back to classic view and use CSR to render the lookup field in the list based on the "Stato".

**Update:**

Currently, there is not function to split string based on the semicolon or iterate lookup values when using json column formatting.

Learn more about [json formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)